# how to cd to folders over vpn?

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, openvpn, shared-folders

Super noob here. Please excuse the wording if I don't make sense, this is not my area of expertise.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

I have established a connection to my work network/server via openvpn like so:

```
sudo openvpn --config configfile.ovpn
```

I can confirm that I've connected by pinging the sever:

```
ping <ip address>

PING <ip address> (<ip address>) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from <ip address>: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=53.4 ms
64 bytes from <ip address>: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=28.1 ms
64 bytes from <ip address>: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=27.2 ms
```

How can I actually access the folders on the server?

I just want to cd in and work with the files that are on the server...

please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if u want to connect to another computer try using ssh , before doing so u need to install openssh-server in the work computer

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

and openssh-client in your personal computer

```
sudo apt install openssh-client
```

after that try connecting using `ssh user@ip` from your personal computer , where user is your username and ip is the actual ipaddress of your work computer.
This was you can connect to your work computer using  a terminal.

or u can host a ftp server by installing vsftpd on your work computer

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

after that try searching in the browser using the keywords

```
ftp://ip
```

where ip is the ip address of your work computer
you will be prompted for typing username and password

Also make sure the network your work computer is  connected does have port forwarding

Comment: I'm so inexperienced with this stuff it's hard to even know if this is the answer lol. I've definitely worked with ssh before to access remote machines. For this case...typically on my windows machine I used openVPN to connect to our work server, and the server folders are mapped to drives on my machine so I can access the files on the server. I dont want to actually ssh into a particular machine. I just want to connect to the server and be able to access the files on my linux machine..does that make sense?

Comment: was able to figure it out...after establishing the openvpn connection I just had to go the file explorer > Other Locations  and type smb://<server name>/<folder> into the "Enter server address" field, and then I get prompted for my work user/pass

Comment: @DerekEden Tried FTP ?
btw Ftp stands for file transfer protocol

Comment: @DerekEden so your problem is solved , happy to know that.Thanks

Comment: thanks for the help ..  guaranteed this info is out there somewhere I am just unfamiliar with this thing and probably was looking up the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

When you are connected to your VPN, you are simply on the same network as your other computer on your work network. So all you can do is access your network resources (such as printers, scanners, etc.). Once connected to your VPN you could try to establish a connection with the target computer to work with the files on that computer using [ssh](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

was able to figure this out...I am using openvpn to connect to the server, not sure if anything would change if using another method though...

```
sudo openvpn --config yourconfigfile.ovpn
go to the file explorer > click other locations
go to the field that says "Enter server address"
enter your desired target folder : smb://<servername>/<foldername>/
you'll then be prompted for your credentials, and it will be mounted to your machine
```